# Django directory permissions configuration problem

Tags: django, permissions, mod-wsgi

I get in my error.log the following:

```
 [Tue May 03 16:42:21 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   [Errno 13] Permission denied:     '/Dropbox/project/www/mod_wsgi/egg-cache'
 [Tue May 03 16:42:21 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] 
 [Tue May 03 16:42:21 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] The Python egg cache directory is currently set to:
 [Tue May 03 16:42:21 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] 
 [Tue May 03 16:42:21 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   /Dropbox/project/www/mod_wsgi/egg-cache
 [Tue May 03 16:42:21 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] 
 [Tue May 03 16:42:21 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  You can
 [Tue May 03 16:42:21 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] change the cache directory by setting the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE environment
 [Tue May 03 16:42:21 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] variable to point to an accessible directory.
```

what and how should i set it up?

UPDATE:

permissions currently:

```
drwxr-xr-x   4 petarpetrov  admin  136 Apr 30 13:38 mod_wsgi
```

Also, both User and Group of Apache both seem to be `_www` for some reason

Comment: What are the permissions on that directory?

Comment: And the webserver (Apache, Nginx, etc) is running as which user?

Comment: you can use `ps` on a *nix box, or if it is Apache, it is in your config file.

Comment: sorry, i dont know what ps is and how to use it. also what should i be looking for in the apache config?

Comment: in the httpd.conf i found: `User _www` and `Group _www`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to create files in a directory, the user Apache is running as needs to have write permissions to it.  Currently Apache is running as `_www` user in the `_www` group, while `petarpetrov` owns the directory and is the only one allowed to write to it.

In order to allow `_www` to write to that directory you should change the group which owns it to `_www` and change the directory permissions:

```
chgrp _www /Dropbox/touchsofia/www/mod_wsgi/egg-cache
chmod g+w /Dropbox/touchsofia/www/mod_wsgi/egg-cache
```

This should change the group ownership to `_www` and allow that group to write to that directory.  Depending on what goes into that directory, more permissions may be required.

Comment: So add yourself to the group.  o.O;